# Query on contact list for select contacts - Multiple URI Android?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contacts, android-cursor, contactscontract

How can I set query on `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email` and `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone` in one query and get ID, Name, PhoneNumber and Email .... ?

Like bellow code :

```
private void getContactList() {
        String id = "";
        String name = "";
        String phoneNo = "";
        String mail = "";
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);
        if ((cur != null ? cur.getCount() : 0) > 0) {
            while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
                id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                //if (cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)) > 0) {
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                        new String[]{id}, null);

                Cursor eCur = cr.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                        new String[]{id}, null);

                if (pCur != null) {
                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                        phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        if (phoneNo != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(phoneNo)) {
                            //Log.i("ASDASDASDASDD", "id: " + id);
                            Log.i("ASDASDASDASDD", "Name: " + name);
                            Log.i("ASDASDASDASDD", "Phone Number: " + phoneNo);
                            Log.i("ASDASDASDASDD", "email: ");
                        } else {
                            phoneNo = "";
                        }
                    }
                    pCur.close();
                } else {
                    phoneNo = "";
                }
                if (eCur != null) {
                    while (eCur.moveToNext()) {
                        mail = eCur.getString(eCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                        if (mail != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(mail)) {
                            //Log.i("ASDASDASDASDD", "id: " + id);
                            Log.i("ASDASDASDASDD", "Name: " + name);
                            Log.i("ASDASDASDASDD", "Phone Number: " + phoneNo);
                            Log.i("ASDASDASDASDD", "email: " + mail);
                        } else {
                            mail = "";
                        }
                    }
                    eCur.close();
                } else {
                    mail = "";
                }
            }
            //}
        }
        if (cur != null) {
            cur.close();
        }
    }
```

I need to have Phone, Name, Id, Email and ... together .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Email` and `Phone` tables are actually convenience uris for the Data table, which contains all data of all types (emails, phones, and more!)

```
String[] projection = new String[] { Data.CONTACT_ID, Data.DISPLAY_NAME, Data.MIMETYPE, Data.DATA1 };
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI, projection, Data.MIMETYPE + " IN ('" + Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "' , '" + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE +"')", null, null);

while ((cur != null) && cur.moveToNext()) {
    long contactId = cur.getLong(0);
    String name = cur.getString(1);
    String type = cur.getString(2);
    String data = cur.getString(3);

    if (type == Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE) {
       Log.e("Data", "Found an email: " + contactId + ", " + name + ", " + type + ", " + data);
    } else {
       Log.e("Data", "Found a phone: " + contactId + ", " + name + ", " + type + ", " + data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved my problem :

```
    private void XXXXX() {
    StringBuilder phoneNo = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder email = new StringBuilder();
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, null);
    if ((cur != null ? cur.getCount() : 0) > 0) {
        while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

            Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id, null,
                    null);
            if (phones != null) {
                while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                    phoneNo.append("\n").append(phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));

                }
                phones.close();
            } else {
                phoneNo = new StringBuilder();
            }


            Cursor emailC = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id, null,
                    null);
            if (emailC != null) {
                while (emailC.moveToNext()) {
                    email.append("\n").append(emailC.getString(emailC.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA)));
                }
                emailC.close();
            } else {
                email = new StringBuilder();
            }


            Log.e("ASDASASDAS",
                    "name : " + name
                            + " \n " +
                            " phone : " + phoneNo
                            + " \n " +
                            " email : " + email
                            + " \n");
            phoneNo = new StringBuilder();
            email = new StringBuilder();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: oh no! please don't do that... you can do it with a single query, i'll post an answer soon

Comment: @ marmor. I am using from my solution and my codes is base it but your solution is good and I accept your response. ;)